# How can I separate same colored connected object from an image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have an image shown below:

[image]

I am applying some sort of threshold like in the code. I could separate the blue objects like below:

[image]

However, now I have a problem separating these blue objects. I applied watershed (I don't know whether I made it right or wrong) but it didn't work out, so I need help to separate these connected objects.

The code I tried to use is shown below:

```
RGB=imread('testImage.jpg');
RGB = im2double(RGB);
cform = makecform('srgb2lab', 'AdaptedWhitePoint', whitepoint('D65'));
I = applycform(RGB,cform);
channel1Min = 12.099;
channel1Max = 36.044;
channel2Min = -9.048;
channel2Max = 48.547;
channel3Min = -53.996;
channel3Max = 15.471;
BW = (I(:,:,1) >= channel1Min ) & (I(:,:,1) <= channel1Max) & ...
    (I(:,:,2) >= channel2Min ) & (I(:,:,2) <= channel2Max) & ...
    (I(:,:,3) >= channel3Min ) & (I(:,:,3) <= channel3Max);
maskedRGBImage = RGB;
maskedRGBImage(repmat(~BW,[1 1 3])) = 0;
figure
imshow(maskedRGBImage)
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, this type of segmentation is a serious research problem. In your case, you could do pretty well using a combination of [morphology operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology). These see widespread use in microscopy image processing.

First, clean up `BW` a bit by removing small blobs and filling holes,

```
BWopen = imopen(BW, strel('disk', 6));
BWclose = imclose(BWopen, strel('disk', 6));
```

(you may want to tune the structuring elements a bit, "6" is just a radius that seemed to work on your test image.)

Then you can use aggressive erosion to generate some seeds

```
seeds = imerode(BWclose, strel('disk', 35));
```

which you can use for watershed, or just assign each point in `BW` to its closest seed

```
labels = bwlabel(seeds);

[D, i] = bwdist(seeds);
closestLabels = labels(i);
originalLabels = BWopen .* closestLabels;

imshow(originalLabels, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following steps:

1. Convert the image to gray and then to a binary mask.
2. Apply morphological opening ([imopen](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imopen.html)) to clean small noisy objects.
3. Apply Connected Component Analysis (CCA) using [bwlabel](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html). Each connected component contains at least 1 object.
4. These blue objects really look like stretched/distorted circles, so I would try Hough transform to detect cicles inside each labeled component. There is a built-in function ([imfindcircles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html)) or code available online ([Hough transform for circles](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26978-hough-transform-for-circles)), depending on your Matlab version and available toolboxes.
5. Then, you need to take some decisions regarding the number of objects, N, inside each component (N>=1). I don't know in advance what the best criteria should be, but you could also apply these simple rules:
   *[i] An object needs to be of a minimum size.*
   *[ii] Overlaping circles correspond to the same object (or not, depending on the overlap amount).*
6. The circle centroids can then serve as seeds to complete the final object segmentation. Of course, if there is only one circle in each component, you just keep it directly as an object.

I didn't check all steps for validity in Matlab, but I quickly checked 1, 2, and 4 and they seemed to be quite promising. I show the result of circle detection for the most difficult component, in the center of the image:
[image: example]

The code I used to create this image is:

```
close all;clear all;clc;

addpath 'circle_hough'; % add path to code of [Hough transform for circles] link above

im = imread('im.jpg');
img = rgb2gray(im);

mask = img>30; mask = 255*mask; % create a binary mask
figure;imshow(mask)

% filter the image so that only the central part of 6 blue objects remains (for demo purposes only)
o = zeros(size(mask)); o(170:370, 220:320) = 1;
mask = mask.*o; 
figure;imshow(mask);

se = strel('disk',3); 
mask = imopen(mask,se); % apply morphological opening
figure;imshow(mask);

% check for circles using Hough transform (see also circle_houghdemo.m in [Hough transform for circles] link above)
radii = 15:5:40; % allowed circle radii 
h = circle_hough(mask, radii, 'same', 'normalise');
% choose the 10 biggest circles
peaks = circle_houghpeaks(h, radii, 'nhoodxy', 15, 'nhoodr', 21, 'npeaks', 10);

% show result
figure;imshow(im);
for peak = peaks
    [x, y] = circlepoints(peak(3));
    hold on;plot(x+peak(1), y+peak(2), 'g-');
end
```

Comment: The actual code you used to reproduce your results would be nice in completing your answer.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting it @rayryeng, I added the code.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Some spontaneous thoughts. I assume the ultimate goal is to count the blue corpuscles. If so, I would search for a way to determine the total area of those objects and the average area of a corpuscle. As a first step convert to binary (black and White):

```
level = graythresh(RGB);
BW = im2bw(RGB,level);
```

Since morphological operations (open/close) will not preserve the areas, I would work with bwlabel to find the connected components. Looking at the picture I see 12 isolated corpuscles, two connected groups, some truncated corpuscles at the edge and some small noisy fragments. So first remove small objects and those touching edges. Then determine total area (bwarea) and the median size of objects as a proxy for the average area of one corpuscle.